# Kendo Custom Widget Filter

Tags: kendo-ui

I am trying to build a custom widget that I can use as a custom filter in the Kendo grid. What I would like to do is have multiple input boxes that get concatenated back into a single string. The control below replaces the current inputbox but I am having trouble binding the value from my custom widget back to the filter. Is there something I am missing?

```
 (function () {

   var ui = window.kendo.ui,
        Widget = ui.Widget;

    var CustomFilter = Widget.extend({

        init: function (element, options) {
            var that = this;

            Widget.fn.init.call(that, element, options);

            var e = $(element);

            e.wrap("<span></span>");
            e.parent().append('<input type="text" style="width:3em;" />');
            e.parent().append('<input type="text" style="width:3em;" />');

            e.parent().on('keyup', 'input', function () {
                //Set Value?
            });

            e.hide();
        },
        options: {
            name: "CustomFilter"
        }
    });

    ui.plugin(CustomFilter);

}());

var columns = [{ 'field': 'FieldName', title: 'FieldName', filterable: { ui: "customfilter" } } ];
```

Comment: What is the trouble exactly?

Comment: I cannot get a value to bind back to the filter. I have tried updating the original input that is bound to the filter but that doesn't work.